# Can (Should) I call a WebService from a Spring MVC app?

Tags: spring-mvc

I don't know much details about `WebService`. But I often assume (due to the authentication layer and response format) the code below is a also web service in Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/member/account",produces={"application/json"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  @ResponseBody String getAccountInfo() {
    JsonObject account = new JsonObject();
    // this queries local DB
    account = restAccountService.accountJSON();
    return account.toString();
}
```

Now I need to modify the above code with extra `WebService` from different application. This extra `WebService` does not exist yet, I am thinking of creating it with Spring MVC just like the earlier function.

Maybe something like below

```
...
// this is the so called WebService to different application
SomeWebService webService = new SomeWebService();
boolean valid = webService.checkIfUserValid(username,password);
....
//this queries local DB
if (valid)
  account = restAccountService.accountJSON();
...
```

My questions are

1. Is the above a common way to do this ?
2. How do I handled the authentication to access the other WebService ? Because I need to ensure that the call must come from the originating app.

Comment: Did you check restTemplate ? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html